# How to implement donut chart in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell How to implement donut chart in **ExtJS 4.1**?
I have implemented Pie Chart and given config `donut:true` it is not working .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
donut: [% of donut hole]
```

for example:

```
...
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    donut: 30
...
```

Comment: Here is a working fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4JQ/6/). If you post your code, we may be able to see whats the problem..

Comment: donut should go in the series definition, not in the chart